# Send HTML email to Jira - raw HTML shows

Tags: html, asp-classic, jira

We're using a community edition of Jira and wondered if it's possible to send HTML email to it and have it not display the raw (escaped) HTML in the issue description. The emails are being generated on our intranet via Classic ASP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a play with the renderer you are using for the JIRA description field in the Field Configuration for the appropriate project.